# add images to html in wordpress from 'Page'

Tags: php, wordpress

I am creating a new page on wordpress and adding images using php code.

This is the code I have so far, which gives me the src url in an array. However i think this gives me all the images in the gallery. is there a way to find just the images on the page and then add these images to the page. See my current code below.

[image]

```
<?php

$query_images_args = array(
    'post_type'      => 'attachment',
    'post_mime_type' => 'image',
    'post_status'    => 'inherit',
    'posts_per_page' => - 1,
);

$query_images = new WP_Query( $query_images_args );

$images = array();
foreach ( $query_images->posts as $image ) {
    echo wp_get_attachment_url( $image->ID );
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

`echo "<img src='".wp_get_attachment_url( $image->ID )."' />";`

Comment: thats good but getting all images in the whole site. i am just looking for images in that page. any ideas?

Comment: Do you use plugins to add images to the page? if yes, what is it?

Comment: I am not using a plugin, I'm trying to build it myself!

Comment: How do you add images to the pages? Do you add a extra meta field and add image or do you use image attachment which is available by default in wordpress?

Comment: just use image attachment which is available by default in wordpress

Comment: Can you share me the screenshot of where you attached the pics, so that I can help you? By default wordpress don't have attachments for page.

Comment: see screenshot attached.

Comment: Wait? You cannot get this type attachment. You are directly adding as HTML code.

Comment: can you advise the best way to make a gallery for so that someone can just add images?